# Django Authenticate Backends with Email

Tags: django, email, authentication

I want to login with email not username like this, please help

```
class loginUser(View):
def get(self, request):
    lF = loginForm
    return render(request, 'UserMember/login.html', {'lF': lF})
def post(self, request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        return render(request, 'UserMember/private.html')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('login fail')
```

Comment: I read django documentation but don't understand https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/

Answer (score 1):

First thing is to create a default email field.

```py
# models.py
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

# settings.py (remember to migrate)
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomUser' # new
```

Next, create your custom email backend:

```py
# backends.py (in-app)
class EmailBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(
                Q(username__iexact=username) | Q(email__iexact=username))
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            UserModel().set_password(password)
        except MultipleObjectsReturned:
            return User.objects.filter(email=username).order_by('id').first()
        else:
            if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
                return user

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None

        return user if self.user_can_authenticate(user) else None


# settings.py (migrate again)
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomUser'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['accounts.backends.EmailBackend'] # new
```

If you plan on using Django's default register/login forms, do:

```py
# form.py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django import forms


class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'password1', 'password2')


class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Email / Username')
```

And then it's only the views and URLs to handle.

[Ref](https://rahmanfadhil.com/django-login-with-email/)

Answer (score -1):

you need to work with allAuth
[Follow this Link](https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-log-in-email-not-username) 
hope it will be helpful.