# Django login form not authenticating. using customUser model and customuserform

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

My login form will not authenticate. when i login using superuser it authenticates but when i login with user model it does not login.

models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    # user = models.OneToOneField(
    #     to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True, default=None)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    ic_no = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(
        max_length=150, choices=Gender_Choice)
    year = models.CharField(
        max_length=150, choices=Student_Standard)
    school_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    referral_id = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    # source = models.CharField(_('source'), max_length=50, blank=True)

    objects = UserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

views.py

```
def login_view(request):
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomLoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = authenticate(
                request, username=form.cleaned_data['email'],          password=form.cleaned_data['password'])

            if user:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('main:home')
                # if not user.is_active:
                #     messages.warning(request, (
                #         f"It's look like you haven't still verify your email - {user.email}"))
                #     return redirect('accounts:login')
                # else:
                #     login(request, user)
                #     return redirect('main:home')
            else:
                error = 'Invalid Credentials'
                return redirect('accounts:registration')
    else:
        form = CustomLoginForm()
    return render(request, 'account/login.html', {'form': form, 'error': error})
```

forms.py

```
class CustomLoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=256, widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Email'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Password'}))

    def clean_username_or_email(self):
        username_or_email = self.cleaned_data['username_or_email']
        if "@" in username_or_email:
            validate_email(username_or_email)
            data = {'email': username_or_email}

        try:
            get_user_model().objects.get(**data)
        except get_user_model().DoesNotExist:
            raise ValidationError(
                ('This {} does not exist'.format(list(data.keys())[0])))
        else:
            return
```

login.html

```
<form
              action=""
              name="form"
              method="post" onsubmit="return check()"
              class="p-3" >

            {% csrf_token %}

            <img src="{% static 'accounts/img/logo1.png' %}" class="logo image1" width="350px" height="350px" alt=""><br>

          <div class="mb-3 image2">
            {{ form.email }}
          </div>

          <div class="mb-3">
            {{ form.password }}
          </div>

          <br>

          <div class=" d-flex justify-content-between">

            <div class="remember-me">
                <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
                <label for="vehicle1"> Remember me</label>
              </div>

              <div class="forgot">
                <a href="">Forget Password?</a>
              </div>


          </div>

          <br>
          <br>
          <br>

          <a href=""> <button type="submit" value="login" class="btn btn-danger w-100">LOG IN</button></a>
          <br>
          <br>
         <a href="register.html">  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light w-100">Register</button>  </a>
          <!-- <a href="index.php" class="link-secondary">Sign Up</a> -->
        </form>
```

My login form will not authenticate. when i login using superuser it authenticates but when i login with user model it does not login.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are always trying to authenticate using the username field. When the user passes the email, it gets passed to the username field in the `authenticate` call.

If you want to be able to authenticate using email, my suggestion is to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63066218/django-authenticate-backends-with-email) by [crimsonpython24](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12467282/crimsonpython24) and **add an email authentication backend**. Make sure you also add the required settings in `settings.py`:

```py
# Extending the list instead of replacing the default backend so both username
# and email work.
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    # The default django authentication backend (works with username)
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    # TODO: Change this to wherever your custom backend is
    'accounts.backends.EmailBackend', 
]
```

My suggestions for other fixes:

```py
# forms.py

class CustomLoginForm(forms.Form):
    username_or_email = forms.CharField(max_length=256, widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Email'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Password'}))

    def clean_username_or_email(self):
        username_or_email = self.cleaned_data['username_or_email']
        if "@" in username_or_email:
            validate_email(username_or_email)
            data = {'email': username_or_email}
        else:
            # In case the user passed the username
            data = {'username': username_or_email}

        try:
            get_user_model().objects.get(**data)
        except get_user_model().DoesNotExist:
            raise ValidationError(
                ('This {} does not exist'.format(list(data.keys())[0])))

        # Make sure you always return something in clean_<field_name> methods
        return username_of_email
```

```py
# views.py

def login_view(request):
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomLoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Either the default backend or your custom email backend will
            # manage to authenticate this.
            user = authenticate(
                request, username=form.cleaned_data['username_or_email'],
                password=form.cleaned_data['password']
            )

            if user:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('main:home')
                # if not user.is_active:
                #     messages.warning(request, (
                #         f"It's look like you haven't still verify your email - {user.email}"))
                #     return redirect('accounts:login')
                # else:
                #     login(request, user)
                #     return redirect('main:home')
            else:
                error = 'Invalid Credentials'
                return redirect('accounts:registration')
    else:
        form = CustomLoginForm()
    return render(request, 'account/login.html', {'form': form, 'error': error})
```